# Does BN_bin2bn have python version?

Tags: python, openssl

I am working on a server-client program, and the client(written in c++) sends public key packed by openssl library to the server(written in python).

I didn't found any python library that can do what BN_bin2bn do in c++, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The [`struct` module](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) provides you with similar conversions, including converting bytes representing integers into Python `int` instances.

```
>>> import struct
>>> example = 'I\x96\x02\xd2'
>>> struct.unpack('>L', example)
(1234567890,)
```